# Import Bootstrap in TypeScript and use bootstrap functions

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm new to typescript and I have a TS file wherein I needed to use `$('#modal').modal('show')` from the bootstrap package. I am stuck now with this error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

after I compile my typescript.

I'm importing bootstrap in my TS file like this

```
import 'jquery';
import 'bootstrap';
import bootstrap from 'bootstrap';

// Some code here
      const Modal = document.getElementById('modal') as HTMLElement;
      const modal = new bootstrap.Modal(Modal);
      modal.show();
// Some code here
```

Here is my package.json

```json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.2",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/bootstrap": "^5.2.10",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.29"
  }
}
```

and here is my tsconfig.json

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Basic Options */
    "target": "ES5",
    "module": "ES6",
    "lib": [
      "ES2015",
      "DOM"
    ], 
    "sourceMap": true, 
    "outDir": "./static/js", 
    "rootDir": "./static/ts", 
    "removeComments": true, 
    "strict": true, 
    "noImplicitAny": true, 
    "strictNullChecks": true, 
    "strictFunctionTypes": true, 
    "strictBindCallApply": true, 
    "strictPropertyInitialization": true, 
    "noImplicitThis": true, 
    "alwaysStrict": true, 
    /* Additional Checks */
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
  },
}
```

I was hoping someone can guide me regarding this. I've been scouring the internet to resolve this and I know it's a simple issue but it will be a great help if someone can explain me this.

Thank you.

To use bootstrap functions in my typescript

Answer (score 0):

There are few changes to how to use bootstrap in typescript. Do follow step and I am sure it will work.

Install Bootstrap and its types definition:

```
npm install bootstrap
npm install --save-dev @types/bootstrap
```

Import Bootstrap and jQuery in your TypeScript file:

```
import 'bootstrap';
import $ from 'jquery';
```

Use Bootstrap functionality:

```
const modalElement = document.getElementById('modal') as HTMLElement;
const modal = new bootstrap.Modal(modalElement);
modal.show();
```

Do let me know if need help or stuck.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery dependency is not needed. Follow these steps

package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    // ...
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.2",
    // ...
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    // ...
    "@types/bootstrap": "^5.2.10",
    // ...
  }
```

Add these

1. script: "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
2. style: "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"

Please note to add `bootstrap.bundle.js` instead of `bootstrap.js` as the former includes Popper for positioning dropdowns, poppers, and tooltips.

TS

```
import * as bootstrap from 'bootstrap';
//...

openModal = () => {
  const exampleModal = new bootstrap.Modal('#exampleModal');
  exampleModal.show();
};

//...
```

---

Alternatively, you could just use Modal import like this

```
import { Modal } from 'bootstrap';
// ...
const exampleModal = new Modal('#exampleModal');
```